# C compiler option in Bazel CROSSTOOL file

Tags: c, bazel

How does one set C only (not C++) compiler flags in the CROSSTOOL file in Bazel.

`compiler_flag` can be used for both C and C++, `cxx_flag` for C++ code. What is the corresponding way to set C only options.

In particular I need to specify `-std=c99` as an option. The only way I know of doing this right now is by passing `copts = ["-std=c99"]` to every target which is messy and error prone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [protobuf](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/src/main/protobuf/crosstool_config.proto) of CROSSTOOL I don't think it's supported. You could write a Skylark macro called "c_library/c_binary" or something similar, and add your required copt before calling cc_library/cc_binary underneath.

Comment: Created feature request with project: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/4672